# Prevent Meteor from scanning specific files/folder

Tags: html, import, meteor, codemirror

I'm looking for a way to prevent Meteor from scanning and load a bunch of files, as I need some text editor like Codemirror that has its own javascript and html files.

Do I need to clean Codemirror's pack and take out things I don't want or is there really a way to tell Meteor that I don't want it to load them ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the stuff you put in your /public/ folder won't be included by Meteor (unless you decide to).